# react native iOS image picker very slow on simulator

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-image-picker

I am using react native to create an app. I am using npm image picker library to access to camera and photo library.

It works fine with the real device, however, when I run it with my simulator it gets immensely slow. The tab bar shows up slow and navigating to photo albums takes like 30 seconds to load.

Anyone have this issue?

Comment: it works fine in real device right? Simulator performance depend on your machine

Comment: may be you enable `Slow animation` for your simulator? `Command + T` to disable/enable it.

Comment: @TuấnTrầnDuy Yes, your are right! It works well now!

Comment: Command + T using remove slow animation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I notice that my simulator was in slow animation mode. I disabled it by holding the `Command + T`.